# Trigger can't work properly when check condition

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I just want to store records in two way.

1. If it exists, it will update information
2. If it dosn't exist, it will insert as new record

Here are the outline schemas for my tables:

***product_purchase_item** has product_purchase_item_id, product_id, quantity columns

**product_stock** has  product_stock_id, product_id, product_total_quantity columns*

I was creating a trigger

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER store_check AFTER INSERT ON product_purchase_item
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  DECLARE X INTEGER;
  SET X =(SELECT product_id FROM product_stock where product_id = NEW.product_id);
  IF NEW.product_id !=X  THEN
   INSERT INTO product_stock VALUES(NULL,NEW.product_id,NEW.quantity);
  ELSE
   UPDATE product_stock 
   SET product_total_quantity=product_total_quantity+NEW.quantity
   WHERE product_id=NEW.product_id;
  END IF;
 END;//
 DELIMITER;//
```

The problem is in **product_stock** table, INSERT query doesn't work when product record not exist, but update query work does properly when product record does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really the INSERT statement that "doesn't work"? Or, is the problem that the INSERT statement is not being executed at all?

What happens when the preceding SELECT query does not return a row? What value gets assigned to `X`?

When `X` has that value, does a conditional test "`foo != X`" return TRUE, or does it return something else (like FALSE, or NULL)?

Have you tried something like this?

```
IF NEW.product_ID = X THEN
   UPDATE ...
ELSE
   INSERT ...    
END IF;
```

(I know it's bad practice to answer a question with a question; but it seemed apropros, since answering those will get you the answer to the question you really wanted to ask.)

Comment: Boolean logic in SQL is three valued: TRUE, FALSE and NULL. A comparison (<, <=, =, >=, >, <>, !=) when one of the values is NULL will return NULL. An `IF condition THEN` will execute the `THEN` block ONLY if `condition` returns TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the desired operation through one of MySQL's standard commands:

```
INSERT INTO product_stock (product_id,product_total_quantity) 
                   VALUES (NEW.product_id,NEW.quantity)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_total_quantity=product_total_quantity+NEW.quantity;
```

see the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Just to be aware, one side effect of this approach is that an execution of this statement will "use" a value from the AUTO_INCREMENT   column, even when an UPDATE is performed. This isn't a problem, but it is something to be aware of, because the next question will likely be, "*why are there gaps in my product_id?*"

Comment: @spencer7593 Interesting remark! I just put together a little SQLfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c99a3/1) to investigate further. It seems to me that the undesired effect is not there. In my sample I have a list of products ranging up to id=8, then I left a gap and inserted another product at id=10. Now, the next auto_increment position is going to be 11. When the Insert..On..DUPLICATE statement comes in with id=9 it fills the gap the next "normal" insert still picks id=11 as the next free id.

Comment: (... ran out of characters before) An INSERT..ON Duplicate (when new_id=3) lead to record 3 being UPDATED and the next 'regular' insert happened at id=11. So, as far as I can make out, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: The `INSERT` statement in the OP trigger has *three* columns (according to the list of values in the insert), with a `NULL` supplied for that first (unnamed) column. It was this (unnamed) column I assumed had `AUTO_INCREMENT`. There's no indication, in the OP trigger code that the second column, named `product_id`, is AUTO_INCREMENT. The `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` approach requires a UNIQUE constraint on `product_stock(product_id)`. The missing AUTO_INCREMENT values I was concerned with would be on this (unnamed) column, not the `product_id` column that I mistakenly identified. I will test.

Comment: I have tested, and confirmed that there is an issue with "gaps" in AUTO_INCREMENT caused by the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` which occurs in MySQL 5.1.53 using InnoDB. Here is a demonstration of the same behavior in 5.1.61 [SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/509ef/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/509ef/1)

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes, you are right! I did not even notice the first column the OP called `product_stock_id` in his post text before. So, the verdict is: *if* there IS an "invisible" `AUTO_INCREMENT` column (not mentioned in the `INSERT..ON DUPLICATE` statement) this *column value will be incremented* everytime the update part of the statement is executed! You (or rather I ;-)) learn something new everyday! Thanks for this excursion!

Comment: yea @spencer7593 both tables first column has AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY. Thanks for observations. My mistake was I didn't know that value return null when IF condition THEN is false. Perhaps, DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the best way. But when I insert new value in product_purchase_item table, is there need DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: @coder: the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a single statement that will perform an insert, but if a "duplicate key" exception is raised (i.e. a value already exists in a unique index), then the UPDATE action will be performed. My SQL Fiddle demo (ref'd  in comment above) shows a trigger that does eseentially the same thing the body of your trigger is doing: checking if a row already exists, and then performing an update or an insert.

Comment: @coder: no, you don't need this for the insert to product_purchase_item (if your intent is to insert a new row.) You'd only use this if you wanted to do an "UPDATE OR INSERT" type operation, depending on whether the INSERT operation would violate a unique key constraint. (Note that in the case of an UPDATE action, an AFTER INSERT trigger will not be fired.)